# Using re.findall in python outputting one set of parameters rather than a set of parameters for each line

Tags: python, for-loop, findall

I've used `readlines` to split all of the sentences in a file up and I want to use `re.findall` to go through and find the capitals within them. However, the only output I can get is one set of capitals for all the sentences but I want a set of capitals for each sentence in the file.

I'm using a for loop to attempt this at the moment, but I'm not sure whether this is the best course of action with this task.

Input:

```
Line 01: HE went to the SHOP
Line 02: THE SHOP HE went
```

This is what I'm getting as an output:

```
[HE, SHOP, THE]
```

and I want to get the output:

```
[HE, SHOP], [THE, SHOP, HE]
```

Is there a way of doing this? I've put my coding at the minute below. Thanks!

```
import re, sys

f = open('findallEX.txt', 'r')

lines = f.readlines()

ii=0

for l in lines:
    sys.stdout.write('line %s: %s' %(ii, l))
    ii = ii + 1

for x in l
    re.findall('[A-Z]+', l)
print x
```

Comment: This can't be your exact code.  Your last for-loop iterates over a single line (the very last one from the previous for-loop) one character at a time.  *Nothing* is printed or assigned in that loop.  Then you print a single character.  In other words, this code cannot produce the output you say it does: `[HE, SHOP, THE]`.  Please edit your question to show a more representative example of your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to do that is as follows:

```
txt = """HE went to the SHOP
THE SHOP HE went"""

result = []
for s in txt.split('\n'):
    result += [re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', s)]

print(result) # prints [['HE', 'SHOP'], ['THE', 'SHOP', 'HE']]
```

Or using list comprehensions (a bit less readable):

```
txt = """HE went to the SHOP
    THE SHOP HE went"""

print([re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', s) for s in txt.split('\n')])
```

Comment: Style nit:  naming your loop character `i` is a bad idea if it does not represent an integer.  Here I would advise using `s` or `line`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data really is in that form (words fully capitalized), you don't even need regexes. [isupper](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods#istr.isupper) is all you need.

```
with open('findallEX.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print [word for word in line.split() if word.isupper()]
```

Added an example.